# Access forbidden

Tags: apache, xampp

im installing xampp on elementary os, but i have a problem. When i am accessing to one of htdocs folders, i get 403 error.

*You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.*

*Error 403*

*localhost
Apache/2.4.17 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.5.30 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3*

I have tried editing my httpd.conf file, but that didnt worked.

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"

Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
        Require all denied
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/cup">
        AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any error messages in your apache log files? If so, please add them to the question.

Comment: Nope i didnt find any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried chmoding the file/directory in question?

```
chmod a+r <filename>
```

Comment: Thanks, i dont know, why i didnt had idea to check folder properties.

Comment: But, then i need to change chmod to all folders, and that is waste of time, changing chmod one by one.

Comment: Use the recursive option `-R` to get them all in one command.